# ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' using python3-gi on RPi Zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, alexa-skills-kit

Straight to it:

```
23.10.19 20:20:23 (+0100)  main    File "server.py", line 1, in <module>
23.10.19 20:20:23 (+0100)  main      from gadget import Gadget
23.10.19 20:20:23 (+0100)  main    File "/usr/src/app/src/gadget.py", line 3, in <module>
23.10.19 20:20:23 (+0100)  main      from agt import AlexaGadget
23.10.19 20:20:23 (+0100)  main    File "/agt/src/agt/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
23.10.19 20:20:23 (+0100)  main      from agt.alexa_gadget import AlexaGadget
23.10.19 20:20:23 (+0100)  main    File "/agt/src/agt/alexa_gadget.py", line 24, in <module>
23.10.19 20:20:23 (+0100)  main      from agt.bluetooth import BluetoothAdapter
23.10.19 20:20:23 (+0100)  main    File "/agt/src/agt/bluetooth.py", line 21, in <module>
23.10.19 20:20:23 (+0100)  main      from gi.repository import GObject
23.10.19 20:20:23 (+0100)  main    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
23.10.19 20:20:23 (+0100)  main      from . import _gi
23.10.19 20:20:23 (+0100)  main  ImportError: cannot import name '_gi'
```

I've been toying with the Alexa Gadgets Toolkit which uses python3-gi ([dependencies it installs can be found here](https://github.com/alexa/Alexa-Gadgets-Raspberry-Pi-Samples/blob/master/setup.sh)) and have hit a snag.

For context, I'm using Balena's Raspbian with Python Docker image, on a Pi Zero W. It just seems to completely fail when launching because it can't load the _gi module.

I've tried various Python version (3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7) with no avail, and also tried installing various dependencies manually, using pip via `python -m pip` to ensure the right pip was used, etc. No luck. Python 2.7 doesn't work at all either due to an encoding issue in the AGT library, however it looks like it's expected to be used with 3.x anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Solution!

It turns out that the .so module for GI simply needed to have the "34m" renamed to "36m", so I added these to my Dockerfile and it runs just fine now

```
RUN sudo mv /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-34m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-36m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so

RUN sudo mv /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi_cairo.cpython-34m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi_cairo.cpython-36m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
```